# More than 2 Visible JPanels in a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I am facing problems while placing more than two `JPanel` objects in a `CardLayout` **which are visible at the same time**. Although I can place a number of panels, but they do not appear simultaneously and I cannot resize them as I want. For a more clearer view about what I want, I added a test image.

[image: What I need to DO]

Comment: create a jpanel and set it's layout to something like grid and add 2 sub jpanels to it and then add main panel  to card layout

Comment: Can I set the of the sub JPanel s\izes manually?

Comment: yes.you can control sub  panel sizes by using appropriate  layout .if you choose grid layout then both sub panel sizes will be same.

Comment: Yes, that is ok. But can I set the size on 1 panel 1/4th and the rest to the other?

Comment: @yes you can but are you talking about sidebar and bodycontent changlable as panel1 and panel 2 ?sidebar and header should not inside of card layout .what i told is if you want to have 2 panels not single bodycontentchangable panel then you should set   appropriate layout  on bodycontentchangable panel and add 2 sub panels to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case you can use panel with [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) as container for constants and cards, and then cards(`JPanel`) with [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Here is simple example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String... s) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    private void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel head = new JLabel("Header");
        head.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JLabel side = new JLabel("SideBar");
        side.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JPanel changable = getPanel();
        changable.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        add(head,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(side,BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(changable,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


    private JPanel getPanel() {
        final CardLayout cards = new CardLayout(5,5);
        final JPanel p = new JPanel(cards);
        p.add(new JLabel("1"), "1");
        p.add(new JLabel("2"), "2");

        p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                cards.next(p);
            }
        });

        return p;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Got a fair amount of idea. It is clearer now. +1 & Accepted